# workbench.xmi have no menu and trimbar Contributions from Application.e4xmi if RCP kills

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I'm working on RCP application based on compatibility layer.
In my application I have one main Application.e4xmi and multiple fragment.e4xmi.

**Case 1:** If I run my application and close it and during close I'm saving the workspace then next time when I'll open it without cleaning the workspace then its work properly.

**Case 2:** If Application is running and you kill it through task manager or simply by eclipse terminate( if you are running it through eclipse). then next time when you open it you will not see then menus which are contributed by Application.e4xmi

**Observation 1:** By using live edition I'm seeing that all the menus and trimbars which are contributed by Application.e4xmi are not available in the application.

But other menus which are contributed by fragment.e4xmi are there.

**Observation 2:** By comparing the ".metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workspace.xmi" before and after UI messed Up. I found that In messed up workspace.xmi there is no entry for menuContributions which are contributed by Application.e4xmi.

I can use `-persistState false` or `clearPersistedState` but I want my application to open as it was close so this option will not help.

Is any thing I'm missing and what is went wrong if application is killed.?